# Regex in R using grep

Tags: r, regex

I have a string and I want to check if it is ending with "(n)" where n is any natural number and quotes are not included. an example of this is

```
"320_50iz_toSTORE(29)"
```

I am trying grep

```
> grep("$([:digit:])",E)
integer(0)
```

Further, I want to replace the match(if found) with empty string. so `"320_50iz_toSTORE(29)"` should go to `"320_50iz_toSTORE"`

Comment: `sub('\\(\\d+\\)$', '', "320_50iz_toSTORE(29)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option

```
sub("[(][0-9]+[)]$", "", "320_50iz_toSTORE(29)")
#[1] "320_50iz_toSTORE"
```

Comment: it will match anything but ) inside the parentheses not just a natural number
`> sub("[(][^)]+[)]$", "", "320_50iz_toSTORE(A)")
[1] "320_50iz_toSTORE"
`

Comment: @pasternak It was based on OP's example, but it can be changed to `[0-9]+`